# Objects in Python classes

Tags: python, object

I think I'm a bit confused with object-oriented programming in Python 3.

What I'm trying to figure out is what's going on here:

```
 class Library:

    def __init__(self, some_list):
        self.__articles_dict = {}

    def create_article_objects(self, some_list):
        for tuple in some_list:
            for single_article in pair:
                if single_article not in self.__articles_dict.keys():
                    article = Article(single_article)
                    self.__articles_dict[single_article] = article
```

`some_list` is a list of tuples containing two article names that are related to each other (something like a Google link thing). Here I am creating a library from articles that I created in a different class (called `Article`). So far so good.

My question is about this part:

```
def get_titles(self):
    """
    returns a list of all the network's article's titles
    :return: a list of strings representing the articles' titles
    """
    titles_list = []
    # run on the dict's keys (=article titles)
    for article in self.__articles_dict.keys():
        titles_list.append(article.get_title)
    return titles_list
```

The `get_title` function is defined in the `Article` class, which means it's an article object method.

As far as I understand, my iteration is on *strings* (`for article in self.__articles_dict.values():`), so how come Python lets me use `get_title()` on 'article', which is only a string?

Thanks for your help, guys.

Comment: The code for get_titles does not match your question (it uses `.keys()`) and would indeed not work; you should use `.values()` as you state, which would be instances of Article as created in `create_article_objects`.

Answer (score 0):

Your iteration is not necessarily on strings.

Dictionary keys can be of any type. Most likely, the keys of `Article`'s `__articles_dict` are instances of the `Article` class.

Besides, you wrote:

> (...) how come Python lets me use get_title() on 'article', which is only a string?

If Python lets you all `get_title` on `article`, it precisely means that `article` is **not** a string. It exactly means that `article` has a `get_title` method, which strings do not have.

You can easily check the type of `article` with calling `type`:

```
for article in self.__articles_dict.keys():
    print(type(article))
    titles_list.append(article.get_title)
```

---

Here is an example of how anything can be a key.

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
...
>>> d = {Foo(): i for i in range(5)}
>>> for key in d.keys():
...     print(type(keys))
...
<class '__main__.Foo'>
<class '__main__.Foo'>
<class '__main__.Foo'>
<class '__main__.Foo'>
<class '__main__.Foo'>
```

Comment: Thank you guys helped me alot, It indeed doesnt work! haha. I should have iterate on the values as you said. thanks.

Comment: @OfirZ It's up to you to find the logic of your program, but from a purely programmatical point of view, you can iterate over the keys of a dict, and the keys of a dict are not necessarily strings. This is why the question actually raised by your post, and which I answered to, is interesting IMO: people are used to setting strings as keys, while anything can be a key.